# How to simulate text selection by mouse in TextBox, but outside of TextBox control

Tags: winforms, textbox, simulation, mouse, selection

Normally, in TextBox (WinForms) after hovering text by mouse cursor, keeping left button down and moving the mouse to the right or left, we can selected any text fragment (even if we move cursor take out of textbox area).

My question is how to simulate/trigger mouse text selection, but begining outside of TextBox control.

For example, let's say I have a TextBox with any text. Under this TextBox we place Panel control with this same Width and X location like textbox. Then, after left mouse button down on Panel area, it start highlighting of a piece of text in the TextBox (just like as if I did it directly over the TextBox).

So I assume that by clicking on the Panel area, special message should be sent to the TextBox, so that it starts selecting the text according to X cursor position (point Y is of course below the textbox).

Hope I was able to explain the question properly.

Comment: What do you try to solve eventually?

Comment: I checked ClickOnPointTool to invoke LeftButtonDown on textbox area but no result. I know I can measure the cursor position and try to count text dimensions and set SelectionStart and SelectionLength, but I think this is a weak solution.

Comment: Or otherwise ... It can be done it with simple mouse operations, ie set mouse position over textbox , call the left button down, and then return the cursor to the previous place, but I am looking for a more "elegant" solution.